# How to create a new attribute with a default value in Rapid miner?

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I am new to "Rapid miner" tool. There are two data set in my process. What I want to do is, generate a process which does the following:

To create this process should use Generate Attribute, Append and type conversion operators in RapidMiner

1. The first data set has a car name attribute, whereas the second data set has a name attribute. name should be renamed to car name.
2. The second data set has an additional other attribute which is not present in the first data set. Update the first data set to add an additional other attribute, with a default value of 1. This attribute should also have a type of Integer.
3. Append the modified second data set to the modified first data set
4. Export the new data to a new excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Hope it will help for others

Please use below process flow

https://i.stack.imgur.com/omfDe.png

Comment: As an additional tip: For sharing RapidMiner processes best use the XML view (View -> Show Panel -> XML). Then other people can copy and paste it and run it.

Comment: Yes David. It's a great idea i will do it. Thank you